# A non mainstream answer for complex mass particle kinematics

Tags: discussion, scope, flagging

This post is about Zephir's answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/16227/what-is-the-kinematics-of-a-particle-with-complex-mass/18678#18678).  To quote him,

> **In AWT (dense aether model)** all particles have **complex mass terms due the quantum fluctuations.** A the case of **photons and neutrinos the complex mass becomes pronounced**. With respect to high density of atom nuclei the mesons are have complex mass too. These particles are doing **tachyonic "jumps"** in space-time and they undergo quantum decoherence and oscillations.

Note the bolded words.

1. The idea he is basing his claims on is "AWT", Aether Wave Theory, a non-mainstream idea. . If you check his profile, he is the one who started this non-mainstream busisness.
2. The post is clearly a promotion.
3. The logic is fully flawed, and non-mainstream.

So I flagged it (a long time back) as non-mainstream. However, the flag was declined (during my suspension, or just before, so I couldn't refute earlier.) saying that I was pointing  out "technical innacuracies in the post".

What is this supposed to indicate? That the answer was mainstream? I would like an explanation for how advertising one's own non-mainstream ideas is mainstream, or acceptable? Does this mean that non-mainstream ideas in answers are acceptable?

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to our attention.

Comment: In the future, try to be as specific as possible about *which* part of the answer is non mainstream. In this case, you could mention that it is about AWT, a non mainstream theory.

Comment: -1 You should have asked the question in a way that didn't target the person: "How does the site deal with members spamming the site with their own theories?"

Comment: @Dimension10 maybe you should have not asked for a suspension in the meta post itself.

Comment: @Manishearth looking at the original, Dimension10 asked: "why is he not banned?".

Comment: @Physikslover Which is basically the same thing. And its the reason why I had that last paragraph in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes sense, deleted.

I think this may have been during the period of time when a couple of members of this site (you included) were generating a lot of incorrect non-mainstream flags (about wrong posts, not non mainstream posts). Basically it was a "crying wolf" situation. At first glance this does indeed look like a "wrong" post if you don't know that AWT is non mainstream. I'm going through Zephir's profile now and checking for more such posts.

Answer (score 2):

The declining of the flag was supposed to indicate that answers which are wrong (including not being about non-mainstream physics) should be downvoted, not flagged. It didn't have a link or otherwise recommend a book or website etc., so it's not spam; it's merely wrong, and wrong answers shouldn't get deleted simply for being wrong.

Comment: @Dimension10 so you're saying the answer contained a link or was trying to plug a book or website?

Comment: Right, but we don't delete non-mainstream answers simply for being non-mainstream, because there's nothing inherently wrong with that, except that they are wrong. Wrong answers get downvoted, not deleted. (As you can tell there is some disagreement among the moderators about this.)